# how to this query in right syntax or right way?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

i write this query using t-sql and give me an error (Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'OR')
How to write it in correct way ?

```
SELECT SUM(Quantity) 
  FROM   Invoices
 WHERE  Invoices.InvoiceDocStatusID = 
        CASE @InventoryType
                      WHEN 1 
                      THEN ((2)OR(1))
                      ELSE 2
                    END
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not really that certain of the desired semantics. Do you always want rows matching `InvoiceDocStatusID=2` regardless of the value of `@InventoryType` and additionally want `InvoiceDocStatusID=1` where `@InventoryType = 1`?

```
SELECT SUM(Quantity) 
  FROM   Invoices
 WHERE  (Invoices.InvoiceDocStatusID = 1 AND @InventoryType = 1)
OR Invoices.InvoiceDocStatusID = 2
```

Answer (score 1):

- You're always checking for Invoices.InvoiceDocStatusID = 2
- The only switch is on @InventoryType
- No ELSE clause is needed: it goes to NULL

So...

```
SELECT SUM(Quantity) 
FROM Invoices
WHERE Invoices.InvoiceDocStatusID IN (2, CASE @InventoryType WHEN 1 THEN 1 END)
```